# From an SSH session to a remote machine, how do I open a file in a Vim session on my local machine

Tags: vim, ssh, x11-forwarding

I have an ssh connection to a remote machine in my terminal window, and GVim running locally as my text editor. I can mount the remote machine via SSH and open files in my local Vim. I can also edit remote files in my local Vim via Vim's support for editing over SCP.

Say I then use `ag` on the remote machine to search my project for a symbol:

```
[user@remote project]$ ag thingy
include/blah/foo.h
1137:void thingy() {
```

Now what can I type inside my SSH session to send that file to my local editor in a tab? If I were on my local machine, I could do something like `gvim -p --remote-tab-silent include/blah/foo.h`, but I don't think the Vim `+clientserver` Remote system can be forwarded over an SSH session, can it? Would it somehow magically work if I set up X11 forwarding? If so, how would Vim work out what remote server to connect to to edit the file? Is there maybe some kind of integration between a vim-embedded terminal session and the `netrw` system that I could use instead?

If I wanted to roll my own system with shell scripts and netcat and forwarding sockets of some kind over ssh, how might I design that?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain this is on-topic for SO, but we do have several other weird-vim-trick questions and an active vim tag, even though using Vim isn't quite the same as programming. Is there another SE site that fits better?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you can easily use [netrw](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html) from your local GVim to open remote files but not the other way around.

Comment: Neovim has builtin RPC over TCP. Vim cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `+clientserver` mechanism on Linux and Unix systems uses X11:

> The communication between client and server goes through the X server.  The
> display of the Vim server must be specified.  The usual protection of the X
> server is used, you must be able to open a window on the X server for the
> communication to work.  It is possible to communicate between different
> systems.

If you set up X forwarding properly, you should be able to open the file, although I haven't tested.  That means that the remote system should have a `$DISPLAY` environment variable.

If you haven't specified the server name explicitly, it is usually in the title bar of the window.  The first one, on my Debian system, is `GVIM`, the next is `GVIM2`, etc.  Client/server arguments need to go on the command line in a specific order and first on the command line.  I'd try setting this up on a local machine and only then trying it with the remote machine.